# How are these array types different?

Tags: c++, arrays, types

So usually when you type arrays for function arguments you declare them like this:

```
f ( const float offset [ 3 ] )
```

But I've been working on a project that has them declared like so:

```
f ( const float ( &offset ) [ 3 ] )
```

What does that change even mean? To my knowledge we are already effectively passing around a pointer. What what coercing it to a reference like this even do?

Comment: Keeping in mind that arrays are not pointers and that the signature is just automagically changed to a pointer in the first case because it's a function parameter, the change is pretty big. It won't accept a pointer argument anymore.

Comment: It is not clear.. it seems that `f` is a function call, so `offset` may be `float**`. Add more code!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
f ( const float offset [ 3 ] )
```

In this case, the 3 is meaningless. `offset` is not even an array, it is a pointer (`const float*`). So this function will accept any float pointer, and an array of floats of any size will be accepted through decay.

```
float x2[2];
float x3[3];
float x4[4];
float* fp;

f(x2);       // compiles
f(x3);       // compiles
f(x4);       // compiles
f(fp);       // compiles
```

Furthermore, inside the function:

```
sizeof(offset) == sizeof(float*)
```

However,

```
f ( const float ( &offset ) [ 3 ] )
```

In this case, `offset` is a reference to an array of 3 const floats.  Only an array of 3 floats will be accepted as an argument.

```
f(x2);       // does not compile
f(x3);       // compiles
f(x4);       // does not compile
f(fp);       // does not compile
```

And inside the function:

```
sizeof(offset) == sizeof(float) * 3
```

Comment: My next question would be why are the brackets necessary? If I don't use them in MSVC2010 I get an error saying that array of reference not allowed. Is this just a quirk of MSVC or how the precedence of the type symbols work?

Comment: @MorphingDragon: Which brackets? The parenthesis? Yes, they are necessary, for exactly the reason your compiler told you. Without them, the compiler thinks you are trying to declare an array of references (rather than a reference to an array), and that is not allowed.